# iPhone - "Edit User Dictionary" is missing

Tags: iphone, ios

Initially I had 5 keyboards

English
Spanish
Emoji
Japanese (Ten Key)
Japanese (Romaji)

I added a couple words to my User Dictionary. Later I realized that I do not use the two Japanese ones very much, so I removed them. After doing that, the "Edit User Dictionary..." option completely disappeared from my Keyboard Settings menu. When I put Japanese (Romaji) back on, the option reappears.

I tried deleting the few words I had entered and removing the unwanted keyboard again, still the option does not appear. I am thinking the dictionary database may have been built to correspond only with the keyboards I had when I initially edited the dictionary, and now it won't rebuild or something.

Anyone else seen this?

Thanks!
Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Womp womp...that was easy. Maybe next time, I'll read my search results BEFORE hitting submit on SE sites. Well [here](http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=11731703) is the answer. Hope this helps someone. Apparently, "Edit User Dictionary" is only enabled for certain languages...with English not being one? ::shrugs:: whatever.